# Wordpress: How to hook into edit.php

Tags: html, wordpress, list, hook, addition

I would like to add an html tag just below the admin posts list in the edit.php file.
So far I succeeded in doing it by using the "admin_init" action hook but then, the html tag also appears in other pages (like post-new.php for instance) which is not what I want.
How can I only target the edit.php file?
Thank you

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Just below "what"? On what page on front end, where? Have you looked at the files in wp-admin/includes which actually implement many of the admin pages?

Comment: Can I be more specific? Everything you asked is already specified in the question, I think: "...just below the ADMIN POSTS LISTS..." (in other words:the table list which lists all the posts in the admin panel). And as it is the "ADMIN post list" we can safely assume it is about the backend of WordPress. And why should I look in the file you suggest as it is not a good practice to modify the core files? What I need is to hook a function properly and remotely in order not to mess with the core files. Maybe I didn't answer your questions and if so, please believe it's a misunderstanding.

Comment: OK: do you mean "above the Bulk Actions drop-down but below the table footer", or do you mean "at the end of the rows but above the table footer", or... and I suggested you look in the wp-admin/includes folder to read the code and find a useful hook; certainly you should not be editing core files!

Comment: Thank you webaware. Just after the table (outside of it actually) but before the admin footer. To be very accurate, I need to add an html tag just right after the "#posts-filter" tag of the "edit.php" page. Please note that I'm not that savvy enough to find my way into the core files. Create a small function and hook it, that I can do.

Comment: Please keep in mind that I don't need to know how to layout my tag inside the page as it is already done and it works. I haven't been so specific about the layout as it is not relevant to my question. My question is only about the right hook as for now, the tag shows up on the edit.php page alright but also in several other admin pages. All I need is to hook to the edit.php page ONLY. My actual hook is "admin_init" but this is generic to several pages of the admin panel and that scope is too wide for my needs.

Comment: The table is rendered by wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php which doesn't have any relevant hooks. Even the bit that renders what's under the table -- display_tablenav() -- has no hooks. I think your best bet is to check for script name == 'edit.php' and `$_REQUEST['action']` and `$_REQUEST['action2']` are empty.

Comment: Can you tell me more about how to use "script name". I didn't found anything about this using google. Thank you. Would it also be possible to detect if the actual url includes "edit.php?" before displaying the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is putting things on the page where you want it, but on too many pages, then try this:

```
if (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'edit.php') {
    // your code here
}
```

That will restrict it to just the edit.php script.

You might also need to test for certain values of the query parameters 'action' and 'action2', by checking `$_REQUEST['action']` and `$_REQUEST['action2']`.

Comment: Perfect. That did exactly what I needed. Thank you for your help webaware.

Comment: Excellent, glad to have helped.